# How to access DOM properties obscured by form fields?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

**Update 1**

After getting some answers I came up with even more complex case.

How to access form's ID and other attributes when form has fields named "id" and "getAttribute"? The general question is: how to reliably access form's attributes in any situation?

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("#myform").id)
console.log(document.querySelector("#myform").getAttribute("id"))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Form</title>
<form id="myform">
  <input name="id" type="text" value="myvalue">
  <input name="getAttribute" type="text" value="myvalue2">
</form>
```

Results in:

```
<input name="id" type="text" value="myvalue">
TypeError: document.querySelector(...).getAttribute is not a function[Learn More]
```

---

I was confused how fields of a form overwrite properties of the form. For example, a field named "id" will hide the actual id of the form:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("#myform").id)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Form</title>
<form id="myform">
  <input name="id" type="text" value="myvalue">
</form>
```

gives:

```
<input name="id" type="text" value="myvalue">
```

How to access form properties without the danger of form fields overwriting them (in case fields can have any possible names)?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

The OP has changed the question now to include `getAttribute` or any arbitrary string as a form element name.

This is simply no different than overwriting any existing variable. For instance, what if I wanted to create a variable named `window` or `document`? or perhaps I want to store some data in a variable named `forms` and place that in the existing `document` object.

Each of these will work, but not produce the expected outcome. That is the essence of this question. "Can I do this?" Yes. "Should I do this?" No.

It is our obligation as developers to understand these nuances. And now the OP does.

What is most discouraging is the fact the the OP now knows this truth, yet continues to pursue this question by changing the variable being overwritten!

**END EDIT** (Original answer answering about the use of `id` as name):

You have confused the difference between an Object property and an HTML attribute.

We access properties using Object access methods (either `.` operator or `[]` notation).

We access HTML attributes using `.getAttribute('name')`. So if you want the value of the attribute as it is written in HTML as your question suggests, you would do that with:

`document.querySelector("#myform").getAttribute('id')` which would return "myform".

But like most questions pondering the 'what if' without a true problem to solve, this seems a bit silly - after all, the element was queried for using its id.

Now, considering Object properties in the right way, this:

```
document.querySelector("#myform").id
```

does exactly what the spec says about evaluating the syntax:

*form[name]*

> Returns the form control (or, if there are several, a RadioNodeList of
>   the form controls) in the form with the given ID or name (excluding
>   image buttons for historical reasons); or, if there are none, returns
>   the img element with the given ID.
>
> Once an element has been referenced using a particular name, that name
>   will continue being available as a way to reference that element in
>   this method, even if the element's actual ID or name changes, for as
>   long as the element remains in the tree.
>
> If there are multiple matching items, then a RadioNodeList object
>   containing all those elements is returned.

Here: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I was confused, even MDN references ID as a property. But what about the case when there is a field named "getAttribute"? I extended my question accordingly.

Comment: That would be no different than creating a variable in your JavaScript code and naming that variable `document` - it is the same thing. It is our obligation as developers to understand these nuances - or ask a great question like you've done.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot simply not to use reserved names. In my scenario form fields are defined by a web service. That implies usage of such names inside of a HTML form. A bad side effect is that any property of the form might become unavailable. And even if I could control names the black-list would be quite large and would depend on many standards. That's why I am looking for another solution. My current solution is not to work with form's properties at all.

Comment: **_I will ask a question, then change the question when I don't get an answer that matches my expectation, then finally will rationalize away all answers because my stuff is more unique than everyone else's._** :: Your nightmare is only beginning @Andrej - good luck to you.

Comment: I haven't changed the essence of the question, "id" was just an example, but not the best one. Your answer is incorrect, `getAttribute()` will fail in some rare cases, that I have pointed out. P.S. Don't call property accessors "Object access methods". And the dot is not an operator in JS.

Answer (score 0):

With getAttribute() you get the form attributes.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('myform').getAttribute('id'))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Form</title>
<form id="myform">
  <input name="id" type="text" value="myvalue">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! But `getAttribute()` might also be obscured. See my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

This has less to do with forms and form fields and more to do with the fact that you've given an element a `name` that is an actual native HTML attribute and JavaScript property. As a result, you are not getting the reference you wish to.

What's happening with your code is that `document.querySelector("#myform")` is correctly locating the `form` element, but then you are asking for the `id` **property** of that and so since there is another element with an `name` that is the same as the `id` of the `form`, the console logs the element and not the actual property value because **form fields are children of their `form` parent and therefore considered accessible as properties of the `form`**.

As you can see below, just asking for `document.querySelector("#myform")` (without the `.id` after it), returns a reference to the first DOM element that matches the selector.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("#myform").id);
console.log(document.querySelector("#myform"));
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  <input name="id" type="text" value="myvalue">
</form>
```

### So, stay away from giving elements a `name` or an `id` that is the name of a native property or attribute of the HTML element and you'll be fine:

```js
console.log("The value of the id attribue of the form as well as the value of the id property of the form DOM object is: " + document.querySelector("#myform").id); // Now returns the id of the element
console.log("The input element within the form is: ", document.querySelector("input[name='user']"));
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  <input name="user" type="text" value="myvalue">
</form>
```

Comment: That's true of everyone's scenario. But you must always take care not to use names that already have a meaning. In compiled languages, the compiler would stop you from doing such things, but not in JavaScript. It is your responsibility to know and understand what names to not use when coming up with identifiers or this kind of thing will happen to you all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a two quite large constructs that have to work regardless of any possible field name. The idea is to borrow methods from a clean object and accessors from prototypes.

A correct prototype has to be chosen from the prototype chain (you have to know were the property was defined).

```js
// To access obscured methods (and also attributes)
console.log(document.createElement("form").getAttribute.apply(document.querySelector("#myform"), ["id"]))

// To access obscured properties (such as `style`):
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(document.createElement("form"))), "style").get.apply(document.querySelector("#myform")).background = "green"
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Form</title>
<form id="myform">
  <input name="id" type="text" value="myvalue">
  <input name="getAttribute" type="text" value="myvalue2">
  <input name="style" type="text" value="myvalue3">
</form>
```